When writting someone’s credentials in a text, is it capitalized?
I wrote "French egyptologist Jean Yoyotte suggested that, as Memphis already had a presence of Greek speakers, Herodotus could have used them to speak to the priesthood."
Should I instead write "French Egyptologist Jean Yoyotte [...]"? I saw this format being used somewhere.
In the same vein, should I capitalize "professor of classics"?

The Chicago Manual of Style (2017, 17th ed.) recommends in sections 8.19 and following:

Civil, military, religious, and pro­fessional titles are capitalized when they immediately precede a personal name and are thus used as part of the name (traditionally replacing the title holder’s first name). In formal prose and other generic text, titles are normally lowercased when following a name or used in place of a name ...

Applied to your example, these would be correct:

Professor Jean Yoyotte   ← title
Jean Yoyotte, professor of classics   ← descriptive phrase
the professor Jean Yoyotte   ← descriptive phrase
professor of classics Jean Yoyotte   ← descriptive phrase

Egyptologist is not a title and should not be capitalized:

egyptologist Jean Yoyotte   ← descriptive phrase

